# calculating the control points for a curved path link in a directed graph with d3

Tags: svg, d3.js

I have a force directed graph in d3.

I'm trying to create a link between two circle nodes with a path element in order to create a curved link.

The path is supposed to look like this:

[image]

Also, when dragging the nodes, the path should remain in the *same structure* when it becomes wider or narrower.

e.g.

[image: larger path]

[image: differentdirection]

I have the right x/y coordinates but I'm struggling to find the right **control points** for this curve.

here's a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/2Lfvcpdr/5/

```
const controlPoint1X = sourceX + (targetX - sourceX) / 2;
                    const controlPoint1Y = sourceY + 20;
                    const controlPoint2X = targetX - (targetX - sourceX) / 2;
                    const controlPoint2Y = targetY - 60;

                    // Create the curve
                    return curve([
                        [sourceX, sourceY],
                        [controlPoint1X, controlPoint1Y],
                        [controlPoint2X, controlPoint2Y],
                        [targetX, targetY]
                    ]);
```

Comment: there are 3 points , where are control points, could you precise...if you could put your code in snippt/fiddle, it will be easier to help you with a functional sample

Comment: @Frenchy- i created a fast fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2Lfvcpdr/3/

Comment: Updated i a little  - https://jsfiddle.net/2Lfvcpdr/4/

Comment: its not clear, i dont understant your problem..in the  fiddle you have only 2 points . so you need 3 points?  so could you precise a little??

Comment: this sentence need explanations: `Also, when dragging the nodes, the path should remain in the same structure when it becomes wider or narrower.`

Comment: @Frenchy - about your 1st comment. not sure i understand. i have two points i.e. nodes that i want to connect between then with a path element.
here's a revised version. let me know if it's clear
https://jsfiddle.net/2Lfvcpdr/5/

Comment: @Frenchy about your last comment - i'll try to explain.
you can see according to the image i attached that when i will drag one of the nodes, the type of the curve would remain the same if the two nodes are close, closer, much further from each other, above each other etc' - they would still be connected with the same path and curve would move to the right direction BUT wouldn't change it's shape.
update original post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256502/discussion-between-frenchy-and-ace).

Answer (score 0):

i have done this little program..you could play with any point.
its a variant of quadratic bezier curve...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<svg width="400" height="300"></svg>

<script>
    var svg = d3.select("svg");
    var points = [
        { x: 100, y: 150 },
        { x: 200, y: 50 },
        { x: 300, y: 150 }
    ];

    // Draw the control points
    var controlPoints = svg.selectAll("circle.points")
        .data(points)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("class", "points")
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
        .attr("r", 5)
        .call(d3.drag().on("drag", dragHandler));

    // Draw the quadratic Bezier curve
    var curve = svg.append("path")
        .data([points])
        .attr("d", d3.line()
            .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
            .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
            .curve(d3.curveBasis))
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "blue")
        .attr("stroke-width", 2);

    function dragHandler(event, d) {
        d3.select(this)
            .attr("cx", d.x = event.x)
            .attr("cy", d.y = event.y);

        // Update the curve path on drag
        curve.attr("d", d3.line()
            .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
            .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
            .curve(d3.curveBasis));
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

what is the relation betwwen A et B?

[image]

or is there a relation between C-x and d-x for example?? (here Ad = dB)

[image]

Comment: thanks.
It's not exactly what i need. in my own code I already have something that works like the way in works in your snippet.
What I still trying to acheive is making the curve a little less steep and also make the curve the same steep whenever I drag a node.

Comment: it will be difficult to adapt without mathematic rule....little steep , it's a bit vague

Comment: I have added screenshot in my original post that shows exactly what I mean in terms of the curve itself

Comment: yes but what is the mathematic or geometric rule?  whitout that i cant transform what yiu want in d3.js programation... see the picture i have added, A et B are on same circle, but are they tangent?

Comment: The relation between a to b is that they can be closer to each other or very far away from each other i.e. the distance between them can be change since both are dragable nodes. They can also be vertical/horizontal etc'. The relation between cx and dx is cx == dx.

I have used a new fiddle. jsfiddle.net/a0cp6qfz/32 I used built in function in d3 which is more easy to work with.

Comment: the problem in your fiddle is when you move one point the other moves too..

Comment: did I answer your Q about dx/cx a and b?

Comment: yes.. ............